# Working with SQL Joins in Propel ORM

Tags: php, orm, symfony-1.4, propel

I am working with a Propel query that is similar to the situation below. Can someone explain what joinSubTopic() is? I'm guessing this is an auto-generated Propel method, but I'm not quite sure how to make sense of it because I cannot find anything in the documentation with a method like that.

**Query:**

```
LectureQuery::create()->joinSubTopic()->find()
```

**Relationship:** 
Lecture can have more than 1 SubTopic.

SubTopic.lecture_id
*is a Foreign Key to* 
Lecture.id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a basic join function auto-created when you build classes. You find it [in the documentation](http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#joining_tables).

These 2 calls are the same:

```
LectureQuery::create()->joinSubTopic()->find();
LectureQuery::create()->join('SubTopic')->find();
```